# RequireJS no define() callbacks getting called after optimization

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am working on a web app that uses requireJS and angular. The solution is fine however I am having issues after optimization.

The way I build the application is by way of r.js. I execute it targeting my main.js that has a define() statement in it that points to all the other files in the solution as dependencies. It then generates a new main.js in my bin/ directory with all the js files it referenced concatenated into the one main.js file. So far so good.

However when I try to load the app in the browser with the optimized js, I notice that none of the define() callbacks ever get called, not even the ones with no dependencies ([]) As far as my knowledge of requireJS, modules' callbacks are executed as soon as all dependencies are resolved.

This all works just fine when the js files are all in their respective locations, with anonymous names, pre build. Its the same exact js just all in one file, so I have no idea what could be different. Other than the optimizer gave the modules names (which is what its supposed to do)

The only thing I can think of is that I am missing a bootstrapping 'require' call to the main module (which is at the bottom of the following optimized file) but I don't have any call to 'require' in my non-built solution and it works just fine.

My script that calls r.js is in a directory called 'build/' which is a sibling of 'js/' which is the root directory of where my js is.

Example of my issue: that first define('../js/common/module',[],function()... its callback never gets called despite the fact that there are no dependencies.

Does anyone know what the issue is? Any help would be ***much*** appreciated.

```js
define('../js/common/module',[], function () {
    return {
        app: angular.module('common', []),
        ngContext: true
    }
});
define('../js/customer_account_list/module',['../common/module'], function () {
    return {
        app: angular.module('customer_account_list', ['common']),
        ngContext: true
    }
});
define('../js/mod',['./customer_account_list/module'], function () {
    angular.module('app', ['customer_account_list']);
});
 
define('../js/common/service/app_config',['../module'], function (module) {

    /**
    * @class appConfigService
    * @memberOf common.service
    * @description calls back to the server to get the application configuration    
    **/
    var appConfigService = function () {
        url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + 'config.json';
        var configReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        configReq.open("GET", url, false);
        configReq.send();
        return JSON.parse(configReq.response);
    }

    if (module.ngContext) {
        module.app.service('appConfig', appConfigService);
    }
});

 
define('../js/common/service/feature_manager',['../module'], function (module) {

    /**
    * @class featureManagerServ
    * @memberOf common.service
    * @description  manages the set of features in the product portal
    **/
    function featureManagerServ(appConfig) {

        this.featuresEnabled = {
            'customer_account_list': appConfig.features['customer_account_list']
        };

        /**
        * @function
        * @memberOf common.service.featureManagerServ
        * @param {string} featureKey - feature identifier 
        * @description computes whether or not the feature should be enabled
        **/
        this.featureEnabled = function (featureKey) {
            return !!this.featuresEnabled[featureKey];
        };

        /**
        * @function
        * @memberOf common.service.featureManagerServ
        * @param {string} featureKey - feature identifier
        * @param {Object} directive - Ng directive
        * @description handles whether or not the feature will be bootstrapped
        **/
        this.bootstrapFeature = function (featureKey, directive) {
            if (this.featureEnabled(featureKey)) {
                return directive;
            } else {

            }
        };
    };

    if (module.ngContext) {
        module.app.service('featureManager', ['appConfig', featureManagerServ]);
    }

});

define('../js/customer_account_list/directives/customer_account_list_ctrl',[], function () {
    function customerAccountListCtrl($scope, customerAccounts) {
        $scope.customerAccounts = customerAccounts.getCustomerAccounts();
        $scope.onAccountClick = function (ind) {
            var s = 0;
        }
    }

    return ['$scope', 'customerAccounts', customerAccountListCtrl];
});

define('../js/customer_account_list/directives/customer_account_list',['../module', './customer_account_list_ctrl'], function (module, ctrl) {

    /**
    * @class customerAccountList
    * @memberOf customer_account_list.directive
    * @description customer account list component    
    **/
    module.app.directive('customerAccountList', ['featureManager', function (featureManager) {
        return featureManager.bootstrapFeature('customer_account_list', {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'js/customer_account_list/views/customer_account_list.html',
            scope: {
                url: '='
            },
            controller: ctrl
        });
    }]);
});

define('../js/customer_account_list/service/customer_accounts',['../module'], function (module) {

    /**
    * @class customerAccountsServ
    * @memberOf customer_account_list.service
    * @description provides list of customers user is authenticated to view/edit   
    **/
    function customerAccountsServ($http, appConfig) {

        /**
        * @function
        * @memberOf customer_account_list.service.customerAccountsServ
        * @description provides list of customers user is authenticated to view/edit   
        **/
        this.getCustomerAccounts = function () {
            return ['AcmeFood', 'AcmeCoffee','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
        }

    }

    if (module.ngContext) {
        module.app.service('customerAccounts', ['$http', 'appConfig', customerAccountsServ]);
    }

});

define('../js/main.js',['./mod',
        './common/module',
        './common/service/app_config',
        './common/service/feature_manager',
        './customer_account_list/module',
        './customer_account_list/directives/customer_account_list',
        './customer_account_list/directives/customer_account_list_ctrl',
        './customer_account_list/service/customer_accounts'],
        function () {
            angular.element().ready(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'], {
                    strictDi: false
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did  you include require.js itself in your html page ?

Comment: I solved this. Unbeknownst to me my optimization was giving my modules weird names.

Comment: @Mil If you think there is value posting the solution, you should post it. Otherwise, you should delete this question.